# Pandas: Excel sumifs equivalent

Tags: python, pandas

For the below table, how do I implement a Python equivalent of the following `SUMIFS` statement?

```
SUMIFS(A3:A7,B3:B7,"<="&C1,C3:C7,">0")
```

[image]

Code for the DataFrame:

```
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1223, 34, 34, 345],
                    'Date': ['04/03/2020', '06/04/2020','08/06/2020','12/12/2020'],
                    'Tval' : [0.01,0.015,-0.023,-0.0005]})
```

The expected output is 1257.

Comment: Please update the question to define the date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Define the reference date as a datetime object.
date = dt(2020, 12, 5)
# Convert dates to a datatime object for compare.
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Apply filters and sum.
df.loc[(df['Tval'] > 0) & (df['Date'] <= date), 'Value'].sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> 1257
```

Note:
The above assumes international date format (D/M/Y).

Comment: `dfp.loc[(dfp['Tval'] > 0) & (dfp['Date'] <= date), 'Value'].sum()` no need to do the double indexing. +1 good answer!

Comment: Or if you like a little more readability you can use `pd.DataFrame.query`. Like this: `dfp.query('Date <= @date and Tval > 0')['Value'].sum()`

Comment: @ScottBoston - Excellent point, thank you.  Updated.  (Personally, I've never gotten on with `query` for one reason or another.)